# 502 on assets rails - nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Hi I'm trying to setup an nginx - rails integration and I'm struggling to understaand why some static files are failing with a 502 error.

It only happens when I access it via https. Http works perfectly

The https is setup using an ALB at amazon.

I couldn't figure a logic since some of the images return correctly while some other fail, for any given type such as png or svg.

At those who fail the browser display Type as text/html instead of the correct mime

Follows the nginx.conf setup of my service:

```
events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}

As for the default.conf (snippet) that goes inside the conf.d directory:

```
upstream app_homolog {
server unix:///tmp/qb.sock fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
# include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
listen       80 default_server;
# listen 443 ssl;
server_name  xxx;
# rewrite     ^/(.*)/$ https://$server_name/$1 permanent;
charset     utf-8;

root /public;

set $maintenance 0;
if (-f /home/ubuntu/public/maintenance_mode) {
  set $maintenance 1;
}
if ( $uri ~* ^/assets\/\.* ) {
  set $maintenance 0;
}
if ( $uri ~* ^.*\.png ) {
  set $maintenance 0;
}
if ($maintenance = 1) {
  return 503;
}

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https"){
# return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

location @app {
    proxy_pass http://app_homolog;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    proxy_redirect off;
}




error_log /var/log/nginx/debug debug;

error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
error_page 503 @503;
location @503 {
  rewrite ^ /maintenance.html last;
  break;
}
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
```

}

On top of it I'm experiencing some errors on my log such as:

> 2019/05/05 18:54:18 [info] 6#6: *30 client sent invalid method while
>   reading client request line, client: 172.31.46.190, server: xxx,
>   request: "���W��O[ �ć��O��L�  �&�X�\,q�.�:�a&�+�/�#�'�    ��,�0�$�(��"
>   2019/05/05 18:54:18 [info] 6#6: *30 recv() failed (104: Connection
>   reset by peer) while reading client request line, client:
>   172.31.46.190, server: xxx, request: "���W��O[ �ć��O��L�  �&�X�\,q�.�:�a&�+�/�#�'�    ��,�0�$�(��"

Answer (score 0):

It's not decrypting the request, which is why you're seeing the strange characters after "request:" in the logs.  I've seen the same behavior from other NGINX SSL configuration problems.

The biggest thing that stands out is that the default.conf file doesn't have:

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/your_cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/your_keykey.pem;

#If you're doing ECDHE
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ecdh_curve auto;
```

If your NGINX instance isn't supposed to receive HTTPS (noticed you commented out the `listen 443 ssl;`) then the problem is most likely with your ALB not decrypting the request before sending it to NGINX.